# NavigationDrawer in multiple Activities and styled line

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

I want to add a NavigationDrawer to all of my Activities. I am unsatisfied with many solutions I found on stackoverflow and other forums. Then I found this [MaterialDrawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) which seems to make it very easy. But know I would like to implement an own style for all items in the Drawer. How can I do that with this library?

Answer (score 0):

The `MaterialDrawer` is built with flexibility in mind. It takes objects which imlements the `IDrawerItem` interface. So you can easily add your own elements just by implementing the `IDrawerItem` interface. There are already some default `DrawerItems` like the `PrimaryDrawerItem` which you can depend on (just extend it) or you can go with a complete custom approach.

To make things easier the `MaterialDrawer` comes with the `AbstractDrawerItem` which already implements default behaviors needed for most items.

You can check out the custom DrawerItems added in the sample application [here](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/tree/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/drawerItems).

A complete custom item is the [IconDrawerItem](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/drawerItems/IconDrawerItem.java)

```
public class IconDrawerItem extends AbstractDrawerItem<IconDrawerItem, IconDrawerItem.ViewHolder> {
    protected ImageHolder icon;
    protected ImageHolder selectedIcon;

    protected boolean iconTinted = false;

    protected ColorHolder iconColor;
    protected ColorHolder selectedIconColor;
    protected ColorHolder disabledIconColor;

    //GETTER & SETTER REMOVED TO KEEP THE SNIPPET SMALL

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.material_drawer_item_icon_only;
    }

    @Override
    @LayoutRes
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.material_drawer_item_icon_only;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        Context ctx = viewHolder.itemView.getContext();

        //set the identifier from the drawerItem here. It can be used to run tests
        viewHolder.itemView.setId(hashCode());

        //get the correct color for the icon
        int iconColor;
        if (this.isEnabled()) {
            iconColor = ColorHolder.color(getIconColor(), ctx, R.attr.material_drawer_primary_icon, R.color.material_drawer_primary_icon);
        } else {
            iconColor = ColorHolder.color(getDisabledIconColor(), ctx, R.attr.material_drawer_hint_icon, R.color.material_drawer_hint_icon);
        }
        int selectedIconColor = ColorHolder.color(getSelectedIconColor(), ctx, R.attr.material_drawer_selected_text, R.color.material_drawer_selected_text);

        //get the drawables for our icon and set it
        Drawable icon = ImageHolder.decideIcon(getIcon(), ctx, iconColor, isIconTinted(), 1);
        Drawable selectedIcon = ImageHolder.decideIcon(getSelectedIcon(), ctx, selectedIconColor, isIconTinted(), 1);
        ImageHolder.applyMultiIconTo(icon, iconColor, selectedIcon, selectedIconColor, isIconTinted(), viewHolder.icon);

        //call the onPostBindView method to trigger post bind view actions (like the listener to modify the item if required)
        onPostBindView(this, viewHolder.itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderFactory getFactory() {
        return new ItemFactory();
    }

    public static class ItemFactory implements ViewHolderFactory<ViewHolder> {
        public ViewHolder create(View v) {
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private View view;
        protected ImageView icon;

        private ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.view = view;
            this.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.material_drawer_icon);
        }
    }
}
```

There are no limitations. You just have to define the type as identifier, the layout which is used, and implement the `bindView()` which will be called to set the data to all views.